# Confused about the Lambda function variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, variables, lambda

```py
people = ['Dr. Christopher Brooks', 'Dr. Kevyn Collins-Thompson', 'Dr. VG Vinod Vydiswaran', 'Dr. Daniel Romero']\

for person in people:
    print((lambda x: x.split()[0] + ' ' + x.split()[-1])(person))
```

This first for loop returns the list of people with deleted middle, but I'm confused as to why "person" is added at the end? Is this the syntax to say that we mean "x" to be the persons running through the people list?

Furthermore I tried the for loop differently:

```py
for person in people:
    print((lambda person: person.split()[0] + ' ' + person.split()[-1]))
```

this makes a bit more sense to me, but it returns this:

```py
<function <lambda> at 0x7fab41922a60>
<function <lambda> at 0x7fab41922a60>
<function <lambda> at 0x7fab41922a60>
<function <lambda> at 0x7fab41922a60>
```

Why? Any help is much appreciated, I'm really trying hard to learn this language but it's still so foggy to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines here:

```py
for person in people:
    print((lambda x: x.split()[0] + ' ' + x.split()[-1])(person))
```

is very poor code because it is using a `lambda` unnecessarily.

They probably meant:

```py
for person in people:
    print((lambda x: x[0] + ' ' + x[-1])(person.split()))
```

which performs the `.split()` once before being indexed.

What this expression:

```py
(lambda x: x.split()[0] + ' ' + x.split()[-1])(person)
```

is doing is creating and executing a `lambda` in one line. The `(person)` at the end is calling the `lambda` with the parameter of `person` which becomes the `x` parameter of the lambda.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I feel like you're most onto what I was struggling with, sadly i still don't really understand the "they probably meant" code. It is clearer, but any chance you could flesh it out a little more, please? The way I see it is the lamba function of variable x returns nothing because x isn't the variable in the forloop, so what mechanism exactly is making x = person ?

Comment: I mention in my answer that what `they probably meant` performs the `.split()` once, which means it is slightly more efficient. Also a `lambda` is essentially a function and anytime you call a function with parameters, the act of calling performs things like: `x = person`. See the answer from Daweo where they have written `def func(x):`. Where they have `func(person)`, python performs `x = person` as part of the call.

Comment: WOW! I finally get it! Okay so to be clear, the (lamba function)(person)
is the equivalent of say max(parameter)! Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's how you define and call a `lambda` in one expression.

Answer (score 1):

`lambda`s are essentially function. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

> ```
> lambda_expr ::=  "lambda" [parameter_list] ":" expression
> ```
>
> Lambda expressions (sometimes called lambda forms) are used to create
> anonymous functions. The expression lambda parameters: expression
> yields a function object. The unnamed object behaves like a function
> object defined with:
>
> ```
> def <lambda>(parameters):
>     return expression
> ```
>
> See section Function definitions for the syntax of parameter lists.
> Note that functions created with lambda expressions cannot contain
> statements or annotations.

So I suggest you not to use lambda here:

```
for person in people:
    print(person.split()[0] + ' ' + person.split()[-1])
```

`lambda`s give instance objects in default, like `<function <lambda> at 0x7fab41922a60>`.

Comment: Why the error then?

Comment: @PCM Added an explanation for that.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond to this! One last question, why does it print what it prints with my method instead of a list of names?

Comment: @Kam Oh, it's because `lambda`s need arguments, whereas if you don't pass them, the inner code doesn't run, so the function instance object is returned. Feel free to mark this and vote if you like :)

Comment: I have marked up your response! I wish I could accept all 3 answers, but I have to choose one sadly :/ 
Isn't "person" an argument in my lambda function?

Comment: @Kam Yes, but if your iterator is named `person2` it will do the same thing. Well `person` is just the argument, it doesn't refer to the object.

Comment: i finally see your point now, so basically what i did is the equivalent of calling a function, say max(), without giving it a parameter like max([0,1,4,10])?

Comment: @Kam Since, max is builtin, writing `max` also gives an instance, but since it's builtin, it gives `<built-in function max>`.

Answer (score 1):

`lambda` are function, `(person)` is calling that function, this should be more clear if we store lambda expression using variable

```
people = ['Dr. Christopher Brooks', 'Dr. Kevyn Collins-Thompson', 'Dr. VG Vinod Vydiswaran', 'Dr. Daniel Romero']
for person in people:
    print((lambda x: x.split()[0] + ' ' + x.split()[-1])(person))
```

might be rewritten as

```
people = ['Dr. Christopher Brooks', 'Dr. Kevyn Collins-Thompson', 'Dr. VG Vinod Vydiswaran', 'Dr. Daniel Romero']
func = (lambda x: x.split()[0] + ' ' + x.split()[-1])
for person in people:
    print(func(person))
```

Keep in mind that storing `lambda`s in variables is discouraged in `python`, so to make that conform with good style you might change it to

```
def func(x):
    return x.split()[0] + ' ' + x.split()[-1]
people = ['Dr. Christopher Brooks', 'Dr. Kevyn Collins-Thompson', 'Dr. VG Vinod Vydiswaran', 'Dr. Daniel Romero']
for person in people:
    print(func(person))
```

When you do

```
for person in people:
    print((lambda person: person.split()[0] + ' ' + person.split()[-1]))
```

you print `lambda`s themselfes, whilst you are interested in their output values.

Comment: thank you so much for making the intended use of that weird line so much clearer and to top that off with a python esque signature to it. This helps a lot! much appreciated Daweo :)